# How do you solve the second part of the question where i am required to derive Simpson’s integration rule?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

When $v(x) = A + Bx + Cx(x − 1)$ show that

$$\int_0^2v(x)dx= 2A + 2B + \frac23.$$

By choosing A,B and C so that $y = v(x)$ fits a given curve $y = g(x)$ at $x = 0$, $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ derive Simpson’s integration rule

$$\int_0^2g(x)dx=\frac13(g(0) +4g(1) + g(2)).$$

Comment: Have you found $A$, $B$, and $C$ as the problem suggests?

Comment: No, i am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: Find $A,B,C$ so that $v(k)=g(k)$ for $k=0,1,2$. This gives you three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: It's better than that, actually: it gives a *triangular* system of three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: @Ian There is a third part to this question which states- Consider now the function $$g(x) = f(a + (x − 1)h)$$ and so obtain a version of Simpson’s rule applicable to an integral $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)dx.$$ Then deduce the composite integration rule $$\int_0^1f(x)dx ≈\frac12(f(0)+f(\frac14) +2f(\frac12) +4f(\frac34) +f(1))$$ Do you know how to answer this?

Comment: That is basically a messy way of deriving the composite Simpson rule with two subintervals. A cleaner derivation is to just use the Simpson rule, which you already derived, on $[0,1/2]$ and on $[1/2,1]$ and then add the results.

Comment: @Ian Ok, to answer the part where I have to obtain a version of Simpson's rule applicable to the integral $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)d(x),$$ I used the same method I used in the first part of the question where i had to derive the Simpson's rule. I obtained the answer $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)d(x)\approx\!\ \frac13((a-h)+4f(a)+f(a+h)).$$ Is that right or should it be $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)d(x)\approx\!\  \frac{h}{3}((a-h)+4f(a)+f(a+h)).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v(x) = A + Bx + Cx(x-1)$. Then you want $v(x)$ and $g(x)$ to have the same values at $x=0$, $x=1$, and $x=2$:
\begin{align}
  g(0) &= v(0) = A + B\cdot 0 + C\cdot 0\cdot(0-1) \\
  g(1) &= v(1) = A + B\cdot 1 + C\cdot 1\cdot(1-1) \\
  g(2) &= v(2) = A + B\cdot 2 + C\cdot 2\cdot(2-1).
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

EDIT:
These equations simplify to $g(0) = A$, $g(1) = A+B$, and $g(2) = A+2B+2C$. Thus
\begin{align}
    A &= g(0)\\
    B &= g(1)-A = g(1) - g(0)\\
    C &= \frac{1}{2}(g(2)-A-2B) = \frac{1}{2}(g(2)-g(0) -2(g(1)-g(0)))
       = \frac{1}{2}(g(0) - 2g(1) + g(2)).
\end{align}

Then the area under $g(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$ may be approximated by the area under $v(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$:
\begin{align}
  \int_0^2 g(x)\,dx &\approx \int_0^2 v(x)\,dx = 2A + 2B + \frac{2C}{3} \\
      &= 2g(0) + 2(g(1)-g(0)) + \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(g(0)-2g(1) + g(2)) \\
      &= 2g(1) + \frac{1}{3}(g(0) - 2g(1) + g(2)) \\
      &= \frac{1}{3}(g(0) + 4g(1) + g(2)).
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, am i right in saying that I just find the definite integral of g(x) in terms of A,B and C.

Comment: You find the integral of $v(x)$, using the first formula in your question. This *approximates* the integral of $g(x)$ (the $=$ sign in your second formula should be $\approx$).

Comment: I do not understand your point above. Once i've found what $g(0)$, $g(1)$ and $g(2)$ in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$ do i use Simpson’s integration rule  to approximate $g(x)$ and replace $g(0)$, $g(1)$ and $g(2)$ in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: The point here is that you are approximating the area under $g(x)$ by the area under $v(x)$. You have an explicit formula for the area under $v(x)$. Substituting $g(0)$ for $A$, $g(1)$ for $B$, and $g(2)$ for $C$ gives an approximation to the integral under $g(x)$ in terms of values of $g$. I hope that's clear. If not, I'll edit the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: I still do not quite understand how that derives the Simpson’s integration rule. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: Thanks your explanation has helped.

Comment: The question I asked previously has a final part to it which i do not quite understand. It says now Consider the function
$$g(x)=f(a+(x−1)h)$$
and so obtain a version of Simpson’s rule applicable to an integral
$$\int_{a+h}^{a−h}f(x)dx.$$
Then deduce the composite integration rule
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx≈\frac1{12}(f(0)+f(\frac14)+2f(\frac12)+4f(\frac34)+f(1))$$
Do you know how to answer this?

Comment: As Ian pointed out, Simpson's rule is basically approximating the given function by parabolas on various intervals. Above, you computed Simpson's rule for the case where there is just one parabola over the whole range $[0,2]$ of the function. The easiest way to think about the third part is to use two parabolas --- one on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and one on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. Modify the computation above to deal with these bounds and add the two results together.

Comment: To answer the part where I have to obtain a version of Simpson's rule applicable to the integral $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)d(x),$$ I used the same method I used in the first part of the question where i had to derive the Simpson's rule. I obtained the answer $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)d(x)\approx\!\ \frac13((a-h)+4f(a)+f(a+h)).$$ Is that right or should it be $$\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)d(x)\approx\!\  \frac{h}{3}((a-h)+4f(a)+f(a+h)).$$